# hashicorps Vault cli "bad certificate" error after successful login

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to issue Vault commands with the cli from my local machine to my remote Vault server but keep getting a `bad certificate` error.

On the remote Vault server I

1. created an admin policy as outlined [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/policies) in `admin.hcl`
2. wrote it with `vault policy write admin admin.hcl`
3. enabled certificate authentication with `vault auth enable cert`
4. associated the admin policy just created with a client admin certificate  `admin-cert.crt`:
   `vault write auth/cert/certs/user display_name=admin policies=admin certificate=@vault/admin-cert.crt ttl=3600`

Then on my local machine I was able to successfully login with this command

`vault login -method=cert -ca-cert=CA.crt -client-cert=admin-cert.crt -client-key=client.key.pem name=user`

which gave back a token. The output:

```
is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login"
again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.

Key                            Value
---                            -----
token                          s.Q2NPAIRwhjNRJqvY8LscgSPy
token_accessor                 bQSI8zGJM4zspnlgvu2XEV1z
token_duration                 1h
token_renewable                true
token_policies                 ["admin" "default"]
identity_policies              []
policies                       ["admin" "default"]
token_meta_authority_key_id    n/a
token_meta_cert_name           user
token_meta_common_name         localhost.com
token_meta_serial_number       4285812225508508199151930131872257251014974781
token_meta_subject_key_id      n/a
```

However any subsequent Vault cli commands from my local machine then get back a `tls: bad certificate error`. I don't think my certs are incorrect as I wouldn't have been able to complete the initial log in in the first place. Rather, it looks like I need to turn off the certificate authentication and use the token for my requests with the Vault cli because I am able to authenticate into the Vault UI with the token.

Answer (score 1):

The `-ca-cert` argument value used is for the Vault TLS Listener CA certificate, and not the CA that issued the client authentication certificate. Your `-client-cert` is correct, and your `-client-key` is probably also correct, but your `-ca-cert` value should not be the one associated with the authentication engine itself.

Comment: Yes I noted that in the Vault documentation too but oddly, that was the certificate that worked. But this isn't the point as I was able to authenticate with the certs passed as above and get back the token. It's the vault requests after login that are failing. Shouldn't the token that was fetched from login and put into  `~/.vault-token` or in `VAULT_TOKEN` authorize my use of the various Vault endpoints with the CLI?

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Matt has the right answer. Please add that second Vault command that is giving you trouble to help us help you. The output of `vault print token` could also help...

Comment: yes we were both right i guess. The CA cert I provided was correct being the cert associated with the Vault tls listener. The problem is answered below and addresses my question of why my Vault requests displayed the bad certificate error when I already fetched the token from Vault.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the configure file.

```
listener "tcp" {
address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
/*
 * Configuration required for mutual TLS
 */
tls_min_version = "tls12"
tls_cert_file = "/home/ubuntu/vault/vault-cert.crt"      // path to pem encoded server certificate
tls_key_file = "/home/ubuntu/vault/server.key.pem"        // path to pem encoded server private key
tls_require_and_verify_client_cert = "true"        // require client certificate from inbound requests
tls_client_ca_file = "/home/ubuntu/vault/client-CA.crt" // path to client CA cert used to validate client certs
```

The `tls_require_and_verify_client_cert` needed to be `false` instead of `true`. I guess this made requests go through mTLS authentication even after logging in and obtaining the Vault token. However the vault CLI commands other than `login` don't provide parameters to pass in the certificates needed for mTLS and so the requests failed with the `tls: bad certificates` error. Turning the mTLS requirement off allows for token authentication of the Vault requests after login.